# Use another class constructor to initialize class

Tags: c++

I want to create a class object, which will use a different class constructor depending on the given parameter. This is what I've tried so far.

```
class A{
    public:
        A(int x){
            if (x == 1){
                B();    //Initialize object with B constructor
            else {
                C();    //Initialize object with C constructor
            }
        }
};

class B : public A{
    public:
        B(){
            //initialize
        }
};

class C : public A{
    public:
        C(){
            //initialize
        }
};

int main(){
    A obj(1); //Initialized with B constructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: This seems like the wrong approach to a problem.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish? This toy example doesn't make much conceptual sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern. Essentially, just create a static method which creates an object of a correct type.

Comment: You may also check Item 1 from here: http://wavelino.coffeecup.com/pdf/EffectiveJava.pdf (It's Java, but you can do the same in C++).

Comment: John Kugelman For example, i want to make a vehicle object. when the vehicle is initialized it is a random type, like car or truck.                                     
Rietty I agree this is a bad approach but i have to work off of someone else's code that defines these classes car or truck,

Answer (score 1):

In a word, you can't do this in C++. The typical solution is to look towards the factory pattern.

```cpp
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
  A() = default;
};
class B : A {
public:
  B() = default;
};
class C : A {
public:
  C() = default;
};

enum class Type 
{
  A,
  B, 
  C
};

class Factory
{
public:

  A* operator (Type type) const
  {
    switch(type)
    {
    case Type::A: return new A;
    case Type::B: return new B;
    case Type::C: return new C;
    default: break;
    }
    return nullptr; 
  }
};

int main()
{
  Factory factory;
  A* obj = factory(Type::B); //< create a B object

  // must delete again! (or use std::unique_ptr)
  delete obj;
  return 0;
}
```